# Windows Forms WebBrowser control - supports Javascript?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, browser

The Windows Forms WebBrowser control (Visual Studio) hosts Web pages and provides Web browsing capabilities to your application.

Does the WebBrowser control have inbuild support for rendering content loaded through Javascript, CSS etc.? Or does it render only plain HTML?

Answer (score 2):

It supports javascript, css and etc. `WebBrowser` component is wrapper of `Internet Explorer`, and it works like Internet Explorer installed on your computer.

`Flash`, `Silverlight`, `Video` play correctly too.

Also, you may interact with page content from your .NET code or call .NET methods from javascript through `windows.external` object.

Comment: Flash, Silverlight and Video play only if you have installed the correct plug-ins, though.

Comment: @Uwe Keim, I agree. I've skip details in the answer.